# generate dynamic fields with mongo (no aggregate)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm using a updateOne() query to update something in my Db.

Depending on the value returned by a function, I will update a different field. So I try to generate dynamically the fields to avoid writing the same function multiple times.

My idea is to store the field in a template string this way:

```
const expField: string = `teams.${newEvent.data.team}.${newEvent.data.position}`;
```

Then I create my query with it:

```
query = {
        $push: {
          evtsGame: newEvent
        },
        $set: {
          expField: goalValue.exp,
          updatedAt: moment().toISOString()
        },
        $inc: {
          scoreField: goalValue.score
        }
      };
```

However after testing the query I realized it had created a new field `'expField'` instead of something like `'teams.team1.attacker'`

How can I dynamically generate my name field?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It works! Thank you :)

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then :)

Comment: Just did it with [expField] though, not [$set]

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sergio Tulentsev for helping me solving the problem, here is the solution:

```
query = {
        $push: {
          evtsGame: newEvent
        },
        $set: {
          [expField]: goalValue.exp,
          updatedAt: moment().toISOString()
        },
        $inc: {
          [scoreField]: goalValue.score
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to force `expField` to be interpreted as a value, not as a name. Not sure if it's possible in the object literal syntax, but you can always do something like this:

```
query = {
  $push: {
    evtsGame: newEvent
  },
  $set: {
    updatedAt: moment().toISOString()
  },
  $inc: {
    scoreField: goalValue.score
  }
};

query['$set'][expField] = goalValue.exp;
```

Comment: Sort of. See my edit for the solution. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @FlorentArlandis Post that as an answer, instead of adding to the question. Because that IS an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this,

```
 $set: {
          expField: goalValue.exp,
        }
```

In the database, The **`dbEngine`** assume that there is a filed **`expField`** in the `collection` and then it assigns the value to it.

Try this solution, Maybe it helps:

```
query = {
        $push: {
          evtsGame: newEvent
        },
        $set: {
          updatedAt: moment().toISOString()
        },
        $inc: {
          scoreField: goalValue.score
        }
      };
query['$set'][evtsGame]=goalValue.exp; // Change Here, It will be dynamic.
```